# Why does the function only add the last object?

Tags: python

Why does the function only return the last object from the request? And does not add a new one to the Data dictionary?

```py
def holdings():
    data = {}
    res = requests.get(BASE_URL)
    res_content = json.loads(res.content)    
    for holding in res_content['data']:
         data['id'] = holding['id']
         data['name'] = holding['attributes']['name']
    return data
```

Return

```
{'id': 5, 'name': 'Company5'}
```

Comment: `data['id']` is a unique object in the `data` dictionary, so you overwrite it each time in the for loop.

Comment: You've told it to set the keys `id` and `name` to a new value. If you add a second one, what do you expect the dict to look like? Perhaps you want _a list of dicts_?

Answer (score 0):

The keys 'id' and 'name' with which you call the data dictionary are not unique for each entry, so you just overwrite the previous values linked to those keys for each iteration.

You either need unique keys, or if you are trying to get a list value for each of those keys, you need to create a list and append each value.

It would help to know what result you want.

Answer (score 0):

As already noted you are overwriting your values each time.
If data is a list of dictionnaires we will not have this problem.

```
def holdings():
    data = []
    res = requests.get(BASE_URL)
    res_content = json.loads(res.content)    
    for holding in res_content['data']:
         data.append({'id':holding['id'], 'name':holding['attributes']['name'], })
    return data
```